# Output xml result into table using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have successfully put together a PHP script to read content of an xml file and output the result to HTML page. The only bit I am struggling with is how to format the output into a table.

PHP Script:

```
<?php
    // Loading the XML file
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("ftpxml.xml");
    echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";
    foreach($xml->children() as $ftpxml)
    {
        echo "PID : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->pid."<br />";
        echo "Account : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->account." <br />";
        echo "Time : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->time." <br />";
        echo "<hr/>";
    }
?>
```

HTML Result:

```
PID : 279
Account : account001 
Time : 137 
----------------------------------------------------------------
PID : 268
Account : account002 
Time : 301 
----------------------------------------------------------------
PID : 251
Account : account003 
Time : 5 
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am lost as to how to display each table headings and the corresponding contents. I am new to PHP so please guide me or if already answered else where, please provide link so I can learn from it.

Thanks

Comment: And the question is: how to read the xml-data into php?

Comment: no, how to display the result in table format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to make the different values different fields in the table:

```
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ftpxml.xml");
echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";
echo "<table><thead><tr><th>PID</th><th>Account</th><th>Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
foreach($xml->children() as $ftpxml)
{
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' . $ftpxml->attributes()->pid . "</td>";
  echo '<td>' . $ftpxml->attributes()->account . "</td>";
  echo '<td>' . $ftpxml->attributes()->time . "</td>";
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Thanks Kojiro, that's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
// Loading the XML file
$xml = simplexml_load_file("ftpxml.xml");
echo "<h2>".$xml->getName()."</h2><br />";
echo "<table>";
    foreach($xml->children() as $ftpxml)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>PID : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->pid."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>Account : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->account." </td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>Time : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->time." </td></tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<thead><tr><th>PID</th><th>Account</th><th>Time</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
    foreach($xml->children() as $ftpxml)
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>PID : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->pid."</td>";
        echo "<td>Account : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->account."</td>";
        echo "<td>Time : ".$ftpxml->attributes()->time." </td>";
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: i corrected some closing td elements.. but this should get you started